# if $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are "totally bounded", then $\overline{\rho}$ is "totally bounded"?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the following definition: Let d be a metric on X, we say that $d$ is fully bounded on $X$ if for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists a finite set $X_0 \subseteq X$ such that $X = \cup_{x \in X_0} B_{d}(x,\epsilon)$.

Now consider the following situation: I have two metric spaces $(X,\rho)$ and $(Y,\sigma)$,  and I have a continuous function $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$, and I define a metric
$\overline{\rho}(x,y)=\rho(x,y)+\sigma(f(x),f(y))$ for $x,y\in X$ that I presented) that if $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are "totally bounded, then $\overline{\rho}$ is "totally bounded? In the solution you must use the continued function $f$.
I thought about taking the funite set associated with $\overline{\rho}$ as the union of the finite sets associated with the $\rho$ and $\sigma$ metrics, but I couldn't.

Comment: (I didn't downvote) I think the title should be more descriptive.

Comment: @DavidLui Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not continuity on $f$ is entirely unnecessary for this problem.

An equivalent formulation to total boundedness is that every $\epsilon$-separated set is finite. (To see this is equivalent, note that an infinite $\epsilon$-separated set means one can’t cover with finitely many balls of radius $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and conversely if every $\epsilon$-separated set is finite, then take a maximal one and consider the balls of radius $\epsilon$ with those centers.)

From this formulation, we argue by contradiction.  Suppose there were, for some $\epsilon>0$, an infinite $\epsilon$-separated set $S$ for the metric $\bar{\rho}$.  By total boundedness of $\rho$, there is a single $\rho$-ball $B$ of radius $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ intersecting $S$ infinitely many times.  But for any $x,y\in B\cap S$ we have that $\rho(x,y)<\frac{2\epsilon}{3}$, so that $\sigma(f(x),f(y))>\frac{\epsilon}{3}$, so the set $f(B\cap S)$ is an infinite $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$-separated set, contradicting total boundedness of $\sigma$.

Comment: Ah, you're right, the metric changes. As I said, I'm tired.